# memory_order_relaxed not work as expected in code from C++ concurrency in action

Tags: c++, c++11, concurrency, atomic

Before asking this question I tried set my VM cores to more than 1(I set it to 2), according to suggestion from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9886246/why-does-memory-order-relaxed-and-memory-order-seq-cst-make-no-difference), this solution worked for the author, but not for me.

The book C++ Concurrency in Action gives an example in Listing 5.5

```
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>
#include <assert.h>

std::atomic<bool> x,y;
std::atomic<int> z;

void write_x_then_y()
{
  x.store(true,std::memory_order_relaxed);  // 1
  y.store(true,std::memory_order_relaxed);  // 2
}
void read_y_then_x()
{
  while(!y.load(std::memory_order_relaxed));  // 3
  if(x.load(std::memory_order_relaxed))  // 4
    ++z;
}
int main()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
      // this loop is addeed by me in order to try 1000 times to see whether the assertion will fail
      x=false;
      y=false;
      z=0;
      std::thread a(write_x_then_y);
      std::thread b(read_y_then_x);
      a.join();
      b.join();
      assert(z.load()!=0);  // 5
    }
}
```

The book says the assertion `assert(z.load()!=0)` may fail. However, I can't fail this assertion when testing.

I tested the program by 64-bit Ubuntu(under VMWare), `g++ -g -o test --std=c++17 test.cpp -lpthread`, I tested under both gcc 5.4.0 and gcc 7.2.0.

I also tested the program by 64-bit Windows 10(not in a VM), Visual studio 2015.

Meanwhile, by searching the internet, I saw some people say this is because of the x86 architecture, however, I remember in x86, Loads may be reordered with older stores to different locations, so I think there can be a order `2-3-4-1` which can fail this assertion.

Comment: __May__ fail. Not __guaranteed__ to fail.

Comment: 1, 2 will not be reordered on x86, unless compiler reorderes them, and they usually don't do this.

Comment: @Ivan So if there's no reordering, then in what situation may the assertion fail? I guess the failure may be associated with CPU's cache line?

Comment: In your example it can't, unless compiler decides to reorder those stores. You might see reordering when there are more than 2 cpus worknig: first cpu sets `x`, second one sets `y`, 3rd one observes `x` changed first, 4rth observes `y` changed first. There is an example at: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order under section "Sequentially-consistent ordering"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The book is correct, the assertion may fail, just not on x86 as you suspected.

To be clear, [atomics](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) make the specific guarantee that no [data races](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/memory_model) will occur. It doesn't by itself guarantee absence of [race conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34510/what-is-a-race-condition).

`std::memory_order_relaxed` is the loosest of all memory orders. It is the baseline of everything. In practice, it [prevents compiler optimizations](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/intro.races#18) around the variables.

```
atomic<bool> x, y;
x.store(true,std::memory_order_relaxed);
y.store(true,std::memory_order_relaxed);

// is similar to...
volatile bool x, y;
x = true;
asm volatile("" ::: "memory");  // Tells compiler to stop optimizing here,
                                // but issues no instructions
y = true;
```

However, the CPU might itself decide to reorder the writes or the cache system might decide to publish the write to `x` some time later. This ultimately leads to the assertion fail.

In terms of the language, this is due to the writes have no [*happens before*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/intro.races#10) relation with the reads and therefore have no guarantees on their results.

Finally, the reason you see no failed assertions on a x86 machine is because it inherently has [acquire and release semantics](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/atomics#order-2) on its reads and writes.

```
// On x86, effectively
void write_x_then_y()
{
    x.store(true,std::memory_order_release);  // 1
    y.store(true,std::memory_order_release);  // 2
}
void read_y_then_x()
{
    while(!y.load(std::memory_order_acquire));  // 3
    if(x.load(std::memory_order_acquire))  // 4
        ++z;
}
```

Which is to say, if `y` is determined to be `true` at `// 3`, what happened before `//2` is guaranteed to be visible after `// 3`.